# Significance of repeating pattern in LttP

Tags: zelda-link-to-the-past

This pattern appears in all the rooms where the tiles fly up and attack you, and I've never really understood what it was.

Anybody here know?

[image: LttP]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's not more than just a stylized death skull with crossed bones (just simplified quite a bit). Beware of my horrible drawing skills:

[image: Skull drawn on top of the pattern.]

Comment: Is that really all it is?  I always imagined it was some sort of bow with a partial arrow knocked...

Comment: I also always thought this was it

Comment: Yep, just a skull. Great work with the overlay. :)